# table align = center || right, difference in <br />

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

In asp.net I have created a table:

```
<table border="1" align="right" class="detailstable StartOnNewPage">
         <tr>                 
                <td style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Miscellaneous</td> 
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px" class="FadeOutOnEdit"><%: this.FormatMoney(MiscellaneousItemsTotal) %></th>                 
         </tr>
         <tr>                  
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.DisplayMiscellaneousPercentage%></th>    
                <td style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.MiscellaneousToDisplayWithTwoDecimalPlaces%></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>   
                <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">TOTAL</th> 
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(TotalOfAll)%></th>                 
        </tr>
        </table>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
```

If the align of the table is set to 'right' it doesnt pick up the 3 `<br />`, but if I set the table to align="center" it does...any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: Why would you want three line breaks? What about `margin-bottom` on that table?

Comment: i've just tried <table border="1" align="right" class="detailstable StartOnNewPage" style="margin-bottom:2cm"> but it doesnt change anything??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9XBEq/1/ check this one margin:bottom is working with both align:center and align:right

Answer (score 2):

> Normally, an HTML table will have a break before and after it. The
>   align attribute allows other HTML elements to wrap around the table.

So your breaks are actually to the left of the table when you use right align.

The align attribute is now [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_align.asp) so should not be used.

Put your table styling, including all that style hardcoded for td and th, into your css file.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Joe R said it is depracated ,I suggest you use `margin-bottom:10px;` for this purpose.